# Allow for a onclick to work with toggle class click on table row

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to allow for a edit click action to be executed along with expanding a table row. For example, if I click on a table row, it expands the height to 300 pixels, but unfortunately it is not letting me click on the edit icon I have in place to edit the entry (or delete). I tried stopPropagation() but that doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code:

```
<tr id="tr_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" style="border: 0;" class="parent">
    <td id="name_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class='cellStyleString'><b><?php echo $manager_info[$row['managerid']]; ?></b></td>

    <td class='cellStyleString' id="title_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></td>

    <td class='cellStyleString' id="text_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['text'] ?></td>

    <td class='cellStyleString' id="insert_date_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($row['insert_date'])) ?></td>

    <td class='cellStyleString' id="reports_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $reports; ?></td>

    <td class='cellStyleString' id="filenames_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $files; ?></td>

    <td class='cellStyleString'><img src="images/edit_report.png" style="cursor: pointer; float: left;" class="x" onclick="editReport('<?php echo $row['id']; ?>');"></td>

    <td class="cellStyleString"><img src="images/x.png" style="cursor: pointer; float: left;" class="x" onclick="deleteReport('<?php echo $row['id']; ?>');"></td>
</tr>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('.parent').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.parent').toggle();
});
```

I also added another one but it doesn't seem to be doing anything either:

```
$('.x').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: nevermind, it was because a table cell's contents was too long.

Comment: glad you got it going

Comment: thanks :) @MisterPositive

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the table cell's length, too long and it was causing it not to work.